# How to copy paste and concatenate Excel column with vbscript?

Tags: excel, vbscript, copy, concatenation, paste

I am playing with vbscript and how to make my life easier. Now I want to run a script which opens an excel file. Copy column C (unknown rows - length) to column B and concatenate it to something.

Example:

```
-------------------
||| A  |  B  |  C |
-------------------
|1|ONE | ANY | 11 | 
|2|TWO | ANY | 42 |
|3|FOUR| ANY | 96 |
|4|SIX | ANY | 42 |
-------------------
```

To This:

---

```
||| A  |  B  |  C |
-------------------
|1|ONE |*11* | 11 | 
|2|TWO |*42* | 42 |
|3|FOUR|*96* | 96 |
|4|SIX |*42* | 42 |
-------------------
```

So far I have tried this:

```
Option Explicit
Dim objExcel

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
With objExcel
  .Workbooks.Open ("Z:\1\one.xlsx")
  .Visible = False
  .Range("C:C").Copy
  .Range("B1").Select
  .ActiveSheet.Paste
  .ActiveWorkbook.Close(True)
  .Quit
End With
```

Firstly it gives me an error that clipboard is full and it is better to clean up in order to free memory. And secondly I have not found a concatenate function in internet for vbscript.

Comment: Note: You're copying an entire column and placing that into `B1`. I believe that will throw an error. I suggest shortening your range to whatever it may be, say `C1:C100` instead, then paste.  Or, change `.Range("B1")` to `Range("B:B")` and see if that helps.  Also, note that you can concatenate with `&`: `=A1&B1` is the same as `=concatenate(A1,B1)`.

Comment: I will note this, the excel column has unknown length!

Comment: It's unknown when you start, but you can always [get the last row](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s9/win005.htm) from a range, then go from there!

Comment: Let me try it I do not know if VBA is same as vbscript.

Comment: I think I have found the solution. I will work it a bit more. Thank you for your direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With some research and the Help of Bruce that worked for me in case someone is interested:

```
Option Explicit
Dim objExcel,LastRow
Const xlUp = -4162


Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
With objExcel
    .Workbooks.Open ("Z:\1\onest.xlsx")
    .Visible = False
    LastRow = .Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("C1:" & "C" & LastRow).Copy
    .Range("B1").Select
    .ActiveSheet.Paste
    Do While LastRow <>0
        .Cells(LastRow,2)="*"&.Cells(LastRow,3)&"*"
        LastRow = LastRow - 1
     Loop
     .ActiveWorkbook.Close(True)
     .Quit
End With
```